# Prometheus servicemonitor interval is being ignored

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

My metrics are scraping every 30seconds, even though I've specified a 10s interval when defining my servicemonitor.

I've created a servicemonitor for my exporter that seems to be working well. I can see my exporter as a target, and view metrics on the /graph endpoint. However, when on the "targets" page, the "last scrape" is showing the interval as 30s (I refresh the page to see how high the # of seconds will go up to, it was 30). Sure enough, zooming in on the graph shows that metrics are coming in every 30 seconds.

I've set my servicemonitor's interval to 10s, which should override any other intervals. Why is it being ignored?

```
 endpoints:
- port: http-metrics
  scheme: http
  interval: 10s
```

Answer (score 2):

First: Double check if you've changed the ServiceMonitor you need changed and if you are looking at scrapes from your ServiceMonitor.

Go to the web UI of your prometheus and select Status -> Configuration.
Now try to find part of the config that prometheus operator created (based on ServiceMonitor config). Probably looking by servicemonitor name will work - there should be a section with `job_name` containing your servicemonitor name.

Now look at the `scrape_interval` value in this section. If it is "30s" (or anything else that is not the expected "10s") and you are sure you're looking at the correct section then it means one of those things happened:

- your ServiceMonitor does not really contain "10s" - maybe it was not applied correctly? Verify the live object in your cluster
- prometheus-operator did not update Prometheus configuration - maybe it is not working? or is crashing? or just silently stopped working? It is quite safe just to restart the prometheus-operator pod, maybe it is worth trying.
- prometheus did not load the new config correctly? prometheus operator updates a secret and when it is changed sidecar in prometheus pod triggers reload in prometheus. Maybe it didn't work? Look again in the Web UI in Status -> Runtime & Build information for "Configuration reload". Is it Successful? Does the "Last successful configuration reload" time roughly matches your change in servicemonitor? If it was not "Successful" then maybe some other change made the final promethuus config incorrect and it is unable to load it?

Comment: When I run a kubectl describe on my service monitor, I can confirm that it is set to 10s. 
Restarting the prometheus pod strangely does not change the scrape time either. It keeps whatever the previous scrape time is.

Comment: I have no idea how it keeps figuring out what the old scrape interval was even when it's been deleted and there should be no trace of it. With both the pod and servicemonitor deleted, how could it remember it? Does the stateful set somehow retain that info?

Comment: ServiceMonitor objects are read by `prometheus-operator` and not by prometheus directly.
prometheus-operator then updates a Secret object with the prometheus config based on ServiceMonitors it processes. You can restart prometheus-operator pod, it is safe to do so. Maybe it is not even running? That would explain lack of updates to your config
Other issue that you might have encountered is that prometheus-operator is confiugured to only look for ServiceMonitor objects in some namespace(s) and you did use a different one.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, as per [Configure Grafana Query Interval with Prometheus](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/issues/2700), that works as expected

> This works as intended. This is because Grafana choses a step size,
> and until that step is full, it won't display new data, or rather
> Prometheus won't return a new data point. So this all works as
> expected. You would need to align the step size to be something
> smaller in order to see more data more quickly. The Prometheus
> interface dynamically sets the step, which is why you get a different
> result there.
>
> It's a configuration of each Grafana panel

Grafana itself doesn't recommend to use intervals less then 30sec, you can find a reasonable explanation in [Dashboard refresh rate issues](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/troubleshooting/troubleshoot-dashboards/) part of [Grafana Troubleshoot dashboards](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/troubleshooting/troubleshoot-dashboards/) documentation page

> Dashboard refresh rate issues By default, Grafana queries your data
> source every 30 seconds. Setting a low refresh rate on your dashboards
> puts unnecessary stress on the backend. In many cases, querying this
> frequently makes no sense, because the data isn’t being sent to the
> system such that changes would be seen.
>
> We recommend the following:
>
> - Do not enable auto-refreshing on dashboards, panels, or variables unless you need it. Users can refresh their browser manually, or you
>   can set the refresh rate for a time period that makes sense (every ten
>   minutes, every hour, and so on).
> - If it is required, then set the refresh rate to once a minute. Again, users can always refresh the dashboard manually.
> - If your dashboard has a longer time period (such as a week), then you really don’t need automated refreshing.

For more information you can also visit still opened [Specify desired step in Prometheus in dashboard panels](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/9705) github issue.